# jquery noConflict on a site that's already using the jQuery object

Tags: jquery

We have some code which is pulled in and used on a number of sites. I've got no controller over the target websites.

We have been using JQuery.noconflict() to stop our code effecting the sites but we've got one target that that is already using JQuery and I'm not sure how to get around this....

Basically when our code is pulled in a few of the Jquery features on there site break.

Here is an snip of there Jquery that us causing a problem..

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#superfish-4').supersubs({minWidth: 12, maxWidth: 27, extraWidth: 1}).superfish({
animation: {opacity:'show'},
speed: 'fast',
autoArrows: false,
dropShadows: true}).supposition().find('ul').bgIframe({opacity:false});
});
```

When our code is included we get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'supersubs'

Here are some examples of our Jquery.

```
<script src="jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfilehere" type="text/css" />'); 
jQuery.get('htmlfilehere', function(data) { jQuery('div.fdmediabar-65144924').html(data); }); }); 
</script> <div id="idhere" class="classhere"></div>
```

I've taken out class names and Url because this is a client project.

I'm not sure how to refer to the JQuery object differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `.noConflict(true)` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)):

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict(true) from the second version will
>   return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

You can then overwrite `jQuery` to be the previously loaded version.

You'll have to keep your own reference to jQuery and use that. See [this for more discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).